# How to unit test Azure key vault (DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder) in java

Tags: java, azure, azure-keyvault

I have implemented key vault service for my java class like this:

```
    private final String keyVaultUrl;

    public KeyVaultServiceImpl(String keyVaultUrl) {
        this.keyVaultUrl = keyVaultUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<String> getSecret(String key) {
        SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
                .vaultUrl(keyVaultUrl)
                .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
                .buildClient();
        KeyVaultSecret retrievedSecret = secretClient.getSecret(key);
        return Mono.just(retrievedSecret.getValue());
    }
```

I am able to connect to my key vault in Azure and get the corresponding values.

Now I want to unit test this. My approach is that when `secretClient.getSecret(someString)`, then it returns some expected string value I set in the unit test. However, I am not sure how to mock `SecretClient` object which I am building in the method. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mocking framework such as Mockito to mock the SecretClient object and its methods. For example, you can create a mock object of the SecretClient class and set its getSecret method to return the expected string value. You can then use this mock object in your unit test instead of the actual SecretClient object.

Comment: I am actually instantiating SecretClient object in the method so how can I mock this object?

Answer (score 0):

SecretClient is final, so you cannot mock it using Mockito.
I did something like this:

```
@Bean
public SecretClient secretClient() {
  return new SecretClientBuilder()
          .vaultUrl("https://mycompany.com")
          .pipeline(new HttpPipelineBuilder().httpClient() {
      @Override
      public Mono<HttpResponse> send(HttpRequest request) {
          return null;
      }
  }).build()).buildClient();
}
```